# how to call a concrete method of abstract class using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{

    public String getName(){    
        return " AbstractClass";
    }
}

public class concreteClass extends AbstractClass{
    public String blahBlah(){    
        return " Hi";
    }

}
```

How to call getName using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking how to invoke it via reflection without having an instance of `AbstractClass`? If that is the question, you cannot do it. To call an instance method of a class (even via reflection) you MUST have an instance on which to invoke the method. Since the method is public, if you DO have an instance you could just call it directly.

Comment: Yes Im invoking the method via reflection. Is it possible to have an instance of an abstract class?

Comment: Only by having an instance of a concrete subclass. If you don't have an instance of a concrete subclass, you cannot invoke the method.

Comment: @user1824107 `AbstractClass.class.getMethod("getName").invoke(objConcreteClass);`

Comment: `AbstractClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getName").invoke(concreteClass.class.newInstance());` so this should work?

Comment: Yes, that would work but, again, what is the point. If you have an instance of `concreteClass`, just do `concreteClass.getName()`. If you don't have an instance of `concreteClass` but know the type you could do `invoke(ConcreteClass.class.newInstance())`. However, using reflection to do this is not only harder it is less performant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `concreteObject` and there are no arguments:

```
AbstractClass.class.getMethod("getName").invoke(concreteObject);
```

For more details you could read the java doc of the method in the class [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29).

Comment: of course, give the above he could have just done `concreteObject.getName()` since it is public.

Comment: @Garrett Hall You probably meant `[...]getMethod("getName")[...]` since 1) `AbstractClass` doesn't have `blahBlah` method 2) OP was asking about `getName` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyTest {
     @Test
     public void test1() throws Exception {
         class TestClass extends AbstractClass {
             // implement abstract methods if exists
         }
         Method method = AbstractClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getName");
         String str = (String) method.invoke(new TestClass());
         assertEquals(" AbstractClass", str);
     }
}
```